# Why is there always a 'meatball' next to the LQ posts item on the review queue?

Tags: discussion, bug

For the last few years I have noticed that  there is always  a  "big red dot" next to that item on the list, ***no matter what.***

[image]

...***even though the queue is supposedly cleared.***

[image]

***Is this a bug, or does it indicate something else?***

Comment: If I am the only one seeing this then perhaps it is my browser.

Answer (score 2):

"This queue has been cleared" means that you've done all you can reviewing there for now (good job!).

The red dot remains because other people need to do reviews: it takes at least 3 reviewers to handle a post in the low-quality queue. (The red dot is calculated for the site, not for you personally, except I think that it's hidden for you for an hour after you view the drop down.)

This inaccuracy has been reported before, and it won't be fixed.

There's therefore no good way to know when there's new reviews for you to do, so you have to keep on checking.

Answer (score 0):

It means that particular review queue is especially in need of grooming; that is, that it has grown quite long. (Exact thresholds vary by queue.)

Either that or you’ve been staring way too long at a [cyan-tinted green stoplight](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complementary_colors) so now its red afterimage won’t ever go away.

Comment: So why when I go to work the queue it always shows "cleared" ? Shouldn't an overlong Queue accept access to clear it? There is a disconnect here...

Comment: Once you visit that queue, it won't go red again for some short spell of time.

Comment: @Cascabel Smells a mite buggish to me.

Comment: Like a cicada, coming to the surface after many years? Or like a mite infecting my eyes?

Comment: The dot is not personalized. The queue can be quite full, but not have any reviews that a particular user can act on (they’ve already reviewed them all, they were the user that raised the flag that put them into the queue, etc.) If you log out or then look at the review queue page you can see the actual number of items in the queues. I collected some info for a similar question on ELL’s meta https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5011/9161